# Is it a bad habit to use true over TRUE for unsigned long

Tags: c++

I've seen this habit many times which is let's say for example this code:

```
void GetCurrentState(unsigned long bState);
```

And I've used it like this:

```
GetCurrentState(true);
```

Where it should be like this:

```
GetCurrentState(1); 
GetCurrentState(TRUE);
GetCurrentState(anynumber);
```

Comment: I guess the name `bState` implies it's supposed to be a boolean? Why is it `unsigned long` then?

Comment: Why are you using the value `true` of type `bool` to initialise a `unsigned long`? They are of different data types!

Comment: Another hint, where is `TRUE` `#defined` ?

Comment: That's in Software Development Kit Generator for some engines that are used in games. But I'd use 1 which is TRUE over a true since its type is unsigned long and true is a typename?

That's really hard to guess.

Comment: TRUE is 1 which is a BOOL. Have you ever heard about it? It is in C++ dude.

Comment: TRUE is not a apart of C++. It is a #define in some libraries.

Comment: Yeah some libraries coming alongside the Windows SDK I think.

Comment: How ever If I remember correctly TRUE is defined like that

#define TRUE 1

Comment: @Frought Windows SDK isn't standard c++

Comment: Ok I thought it is C++ as well. Doesn't matter, however which way should it be?

Comment: The method (?) is asking for an unsigned long. Why try to pass it a boolean? The method is not asking for that!

Comment: @Frought: If `TRUE` is defined as `1`,  then it's of type `int`, not `bool`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, IMO, using numbers to represent Boolean values is poor programming practice.

The practice is an ancient one for languages that don't have a Boolean type.

A Boolean data type will help prevent issues where the program may be passing other values than 1 for *true* and a comparison is made for 1 rather than *not zero*.

So comply with legacy code, if you must.  Promote the Boolean type and you will be rewarded (with fewer defects in your code).